# Plugin not found even though not specified anywhere

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

So I just moved to iTerm2 and zsh, along with OMZ. I am getting this error constantly when opening up a new terminal session:

```
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'hub' not found
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'colored-man-page' not found
```

Now, even uninstalling and installing OMZ I get this. I am not sure where this plugin is called but my `zshrc` file contains:

```
plugins=(git wd last-working-dir)
export ZSH=/Users/doron.katz/.local/share/oh-my-zsh
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source /Users/doron.katz/.local/share/oh-my-zsh/plugins/colored-man-page/colored-man-pages.plugin.zsh
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='nerdfont-complete'
source  ~/powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(ssh dir vcs newline status)
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=()
POWERLEVEL9K_PROMPT_ADD_NEWLINE=true
```

I have even added `source /Users/doron.katz/.local/share/oh-my-zsh/plugins/colored-man-pages/colored-man-pages.plugin.zsh`.

The folder exists, but not sure who is calling that plugin anyway.. THe same for HUB.

Please help!